# Someone is using my email to create online accounts; what should I do?

Tags: email, identity-management

I suspect it’s an attempt at getting into an existing account using a leaked email/password combo. I update my passwords regularly and do not reuse, so I don’t think the attack will be successful, but it is still frustrating. Right now, I’m changing the password of the accounts created and activating two-factor authentification to make sure I keep control of accounts using my email. Then I communicate with the customer service of the different services to let them know what happened. Is this a good idea?

I’m thinking of moving on to a new email; is the hassle worth it? What else should or could I do?

Comment: This question lakes details. How can they create new accounts if they do not have control of your email? (Most services require you click the link in the email.) Are you referring to "trying to login to your accounts"?

Comment: I get emails asking me to confirm my email for the creation of a new account on services I don’t use.

Comment: If you never click the verification links, then you shouldn't have much to worry about. In the meantime, try googling your email address to see where people might be getting it from.

Comment: There is no "attack". There isn't even a security issue. It's just annoying.

Comment: @schroeder I would say this is a security issue because these accounts will be sometimes created with the personal information of a identity theft victim. If I have access to that info, via the account using my email, then it's a security issue from the perspective of the identity theft victim.

Comment: @BradleyThomas your logic is backwards. The fact that new accounts are set up using one's email address is not the security issue in your scenario. The breach of personal data is. And your claim that the new account set up by someone else provides access to personal data is also backwards. One needs the personal data first in order to enter that data into the new account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m thinking of moving on to a new email; is the hassle worth it?

Moving to a new email for each account is a good idea since the attackers already know your current email. There is little benefit though to completely drop the email, so it might not be worth it for you.

> What else should or could I do?

You should always use different emails for different accounts. Depending on the accounts you use, if the number of your emails is quite limited, you should group the accounts of the same security level. This way, attackers won't know which email to use at once.

I think Outlook supports multiple emails for the same account.

It's not too inconvenient. Just change it in settings of each service.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing much you can do. Check this very interesting chain from Google: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/6055937?hl=en

> I have tried working with them, but they **claim** they were able to register the email, with the identical name (no dot). As this "bug " is now sharing that person's PII with me, and Google is located in California, I would think they would want to resolve this issue. However, there is no way listed of speaking/contacting someone at Google to resolve this.

Claim, being the keyword here. You will see this is a recurring pattern of phishing information. People will contact the other side, which claims that they get the same emails and when you ask them to forward one then communications stop.

Not much point changing emails, it can happen for any addresses, like other spam does. The bothersome thing is that those emails get through your provider's filters whereas spam doesn't.

My suggestion is to whitelist addresses for your account instead of blacklisting. This way only certain people can get to your inbox and when you want to register, you can always access your junk mail and add this new domain to your whitelist.